# How to implement break into javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to when `if ($('#WrapOfPasengers div[data-number]').size() >= 6)` condition equal with **true** then another codes into `click` event  don't run and  `break` .I use `return false;` but this don't work .
How to do this?

```js
$('#btnMan').click(function() {
  if ($('#WrapOfPasengers div[data-number]').size() >= 6) {
    $('#Modal .messageDanger').text('توجه!! امکان انتخاب بیش از 6 صندلی وجود ندارد.');
    $('#Modal').modal('show');
    ///////////////////////////
    return false;
    ///////////////////////////
  }
  if (ValidateGender(SeatNo, $('.seats > ul:nth-child(1) > li').length, 'man')) {
    //-------------------
    $('#WrapOfPasengers').append('<div class="btn-group" data-number="' + SeatNo + '"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">  <span class="soap-icon-close" style="font-size: 25px"></span>     &nbsp;<span class="spanNum">' + SeatNo + '</span>&nbsp;<span class="soap-icon-man-3" style="font-size: 25px"></span> </button></div>');
    $('#' + SeatNo).addClass('selected');
    $('div[data-number=' + SeatNo + ']').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('data-number');
      $('#' + id).removeClass('btn-info').removeClass('selected').removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-default');
      $(this).remove();
    });
    $('#ModalInfo').modal('hide');
    $('#' + SeatNo).switchClass("btn-default", "btn-info");
  } else {
    $('#ModalInfo').modal('hide');

  }
});
```

Comment: why you think, that _this don't work_? can you provide [mcve] that reproduce your problem?

Comment: It should work. If the button is a submit button, you want `function (e) { e.preventDefault()`

Comment: I test this number but after return false statment : ValidateGender function run always

Comment: Nothing runs after a return false. You likely do not go through your `ìf` the way you think you do or you call the ValidateGender elsewhere too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using this :

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

well

```
return false;
```

should work properly as well.

Comment: event.returnValue would not return from the function before executing the next statement